# Read local configuration file into google colab (Python)

Tags: python, file, google-colaboratory

## Load NEAT config file

Unable to call upon a local file on google colab (first time using this). I uploaded the file but unable to call the information from the desired configuration file. Any pointers? Thanks.

```
local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'cartpole.config')
config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                    neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                    config_path)
population = neat.Population(config)
```

```
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
from google.colab import files
import os
import neat

# Upload the configuration file to Colab
uploaded = files.upload()

# Get the path to the uploaded file
config_path = list(uploaded.keys())[0]

# Create the configuration object
config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                     neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                     config_path)

# Create the population object
population = neat.Population(config)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).